# Where will the object be created in java

Tags: java, java-8, heap-memory

Below is a question that was raised by one of my friends during a discussion but both of us didn't know what the actual answer is.

```
public class Test {
static int i = 5;
static String str = "Welcome";
static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

In the object code, when JVM instance is created and it goes to create all three objects, where does it creates it

```
- Inside memory/metadata area
- Inside heap area
```

We know that `memory area` holds all data related to class(including static references) and `heap area` holds all instance variables of a class.

But for the class above

```
- int variable is created(We assume that it will be created in method area
- Not sure about the other two object(String and HashMap)
```

Correct us if we have misunderstood anything and help us in understanding how these variable will be store in java

Comment: All objects are created on the heap as you stated.

Comment: *1 mistake*: the static fields are initialized when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

For the Oracle JVM, there is a special object for each class to hold it's static fields. You can see this special object if you do a heap dump.

NOTE: There is no specification of where static members are stored, so it could be anywhere based on the JVM.